# In dplyr summarise() I can build off of newly created columns, how can I do this in data.table?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am dplyr user. I am constantly using its joins, piping function, group_by, and summarise functions but one-day data.table came along took a large data set that I was working on and reduced the time for my calculation by 87%. Now I want to switch from dplyr to data.table. However, in my code, I have the following table:

```
structure(list(tariff_label = c("tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", 
"tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", "tv_special", 
"tv_special", "tv_special", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff", 
"tariff", "tariff", "tariff", "tariff"), d = c("7", "7", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "7", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3"), h = c("17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 
55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 
71), period = c("day", "day", "day", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", "night", 
"night", "night", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day"), week_period = c("weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", 
"weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", 
"weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", 
"weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", 
"weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", 
"weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", 
"weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "weekend", "week day", 
"week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", 
"week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", 
"week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", 
"week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", 
"week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", "week day", 
"week day"), center_id = c("12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", 
"12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc", "12_aDb4_09083641_aaHcc"
), network_price = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 
3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 3.85, 
3.85, 3.85, 3.85), group_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-71L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I then did the following calculations

```
df$network_price <- as.numeric(df$network_price)
df$group_id<-factor(df$group_id)
df$id<-as.numeric(df$id)
df<-data.table(df)
daily_cap<- 13.50

# Main function in regards to my question
msub_list<- df %>% group_by(group_id) %>% 
  summarise(cum_sum = list(cumsum(network_price)),
            exceeded = list(unlist(cum_sum) > daily_cap),
            exceeded_indicator = any(unlist(exceeded)),
            last_false = sum(!unlist(exceeded)),
            start_group = range(id)[1],
            end_group = start_group + last_false - 1 + exceeded_indicator,
            subdf = list(df[start_group:end_group,]),
            difference = daily_cap - unlist(cum_sum)[last_false]
  )
```

My goal is to now implement the same calculation in data.table for what I did in `msub_list`. Notice how the columns make calculations using previous columns. For example, the column **exceeded** uses the newly created column **cum_sum** and so on. I tried to implement this with data.table but I got the error object **cum_sum is not found**. Is there a way to implement this in data.table. Just for your info, I did this calculation in this way so as to avoid using a loop for these calculations, and when I say a loop I mean using a for loop or by splitting the data table and using `lapply()`. This has greatly sped up my code and I am only looking for solutions with data.table. I tried searching online for this but I can't find any solutions. Here is how my attempt looked like

```
# Attempt with data.table
msub_list <- x[, .(cum_sum = list(cumsum(tariff_price)),
                      exceeded = list(unlist(cum_sum) > daily_cap),
                      exceeded_indicator = any(unlist(exceeded)),
                      last_false = sum(!unlist(exceeded)),
                      start_group = range(id)[1],
                      end_group = start_group + last_false - 1 + exceeded_indicator,
                      subdf = list(x[start_group:end_group,]),
                      difference = daily_cap - unlist(cum_sum)[last_false]
                      ),
                   by = group_id]
```

Comment: Not an answer but did you know you could use `data.table` as a backend for `dplyr`? The speed of `data.table` with the syntax of `dplyr` -- the `dtplyr` package does the conversion for you. See https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org

Comment: The answer I provided is a data.table analog; however, you can probably make both the dplyr and data.table versions more consise and probably faster if you indicate which columns in the output you actually need to retain. Not everything needs to be nested lists, that are repeatedly unnested, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{}` to create temporary columns, and then choose which ones to keep.

The below gets you the same information as the dplyr pipeline

```
df[, {
  cum_sum  = list(list(cumsum(network_price)));
  exceeded = list(list(unlist(cum_sum)>daily_cap));
  exceeded_indicator = any(unlist(exceeded));
  start_group = range(id)[1];
  last_false=sum(unlist(exceeded)==F);
  end_group = start_group+last_false-1+exceeded_indicator;
  subdf = list(list(df[start_group:end_group,]));
  difference = daily_cap - unlist(cum_sum)[last_false];
  list(cum_sum = cum_sum,
       exceeded =exceeded,
       exceeded_indicator = exceeded_indicator,
       start_group = start_group,
       last_false = last_false,
       end_group = end_group,
       subdf = subdf,
       difference = difference)
}, by=group_id]
```

Output:

```
   group_id   cum_sum  exceeded exceeded_indicator start_group last_false end_group     subdf difference
1:        1 <list[1]> <list[1]>               TRUE           1          9        10 <list[1]>       0.90
2:        2 <list[1]> <list[1]>               TRUE          25          9        34 <list[1]>       0.90
3:        3 <list[1]> <list[1]>               TRUE          49          4        53 <list[1]>       0.55
```

Comment: What if I wanted to take the, say, `difference` and set it as a new column using `:=` ?

Comment: Perhaps you asking something that should be its own question?  However, I believe you can do something like this: `df = data.table( gp = c(1,1,2,2), a = c(1,2,3,4),b = c(12,19,32,100)) ; df[, k:={tmp = max(a)*max(a); b-tmp}, by=.(gp)][]`

Comment: Didn't know if I should create a new question. However, your solution is exactly what I was after. Great to learn. Thank you

Comment: no worries.. as you can see in the toy example in my comment, `k` will be assigned to the last value within the `{}` sequence

Comment: I have now tried using temp columns to create multiple columns too `df[, (x) := {tmp = max(a)*max(a); .(tmp, b-tmp)}, .(gp)]` where `x <- c('c', 'd')` Great stuff

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [`table.express` package](https://asardaes.github.io/table.express/articles/table.express.html).
Now that version 0.4.0 is out,
it should support the syntax you were using directly:

```
library(table.express)

df %>%
    as.data.table %>%
    mutate(
        network_price = as.numeric(network_price),
        group_id = factor(group_id),
        id = as.integer(id)
    ) %>%
    group_by(group_id) %>% 
    summarise(
        cum_sum = list(cumsum(network_price)),
        exceeded = list(unlist(cum_sum) > daily_cap),
        exceeded_indicator = any(unlist(exceeded)),
        last_false = sum(!unlist(exceeded)),
        start_group = range(id)[1],
        end_group = start_group + last_false - 1 + exceeded_indicator,
        subdf = list(df[start_group:end_group,]),
        difference = daily_cap - unlist(cum_sum)[last_false]
    )
```

Kudos to langtang's answer,
which showed me how to improve `table.express` for this scenario.
However, note that doing something like this with `data.table` may actually turn off some if the optimisations it can do,
since it can optimise functions like `min` or `max` if used outside `{}`.

The original options I had provided in this answer:

```
ans <- df %>%
    as.data.table %>%
    mutate(
        network_price = as.numeric(network_price),
        group_id = factor(group_id),
        id = as.integer(id)
    ) %>%
    group_by(group_id) %>%
    select({
        cum_sum  = cumsum(network_price)
        exceeded = cum_sum > daily_cap
        exceeded_indicator = any(exceeded)
        start_group = min(id)
        last_false = sum(!exceeded)
        end_group = start_group + last_false - 1L + exceeded_indicator
        difference = daily_cap - cum_sum[last_false]
        list(
            cum_sum = list(cum_sum),
            exceeded = list(exceeded),
            exceeded_indicator = exceeded_indicator,
            start_group = start_group,
            end_group = end_group,
            last_false = last_false,
            difference = difference,
            subdf = list(df[start_group:end_group, ])
        )
    })
```

Or the "long" verbose way that ends up with fewer nested lists that might not be necessary:

```
ans <- df %>%
    as.data.table %>%
    mutate(
        network_price = as.numeric(network_price),
        group_id = factor(group_id),
        id = as.integer(id)
    ) %>%
    key_by(group_id) %>%
    transmute(cum_sum = cumsum(network_price), id) %>%
    mutate(exceeded = cum_sum > daily_cap) %>%
    key_by(group_id) %>%
    summarise(
        exceeded_indicator = any(exceeded),
        start_group = min(id),
        last_false = sum(!exceeded),
        difference = daily_cap - cum_sum[sum(!exceeded)]
    ) %>%
    mutate(end_group = start_group + last_false - 1L + exceeded_indicator) %>%
    key_by(group_id) %>%
    mutate(subdf = list(df[start_group:end_group, ]))
```

I use `key_by` here because I think that might help optimise the repeated grouped calls.